# How Do I Select Just a Latitude or Longitude From A Geography Point

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.3

In Postgresql you can use `ST_TEXTFROMGEOGRAPHY` in a query to return a geography point in text form. Then whatever reads the query can parse the text to pull out the latitude and longitude of the geography point.

When working with a geometry, you can use `ST_X` and `ST_Y` to return the x and y, respectively, of a geometry point as separate columns. I have not found a similar function for geography points.

What is the simplest way to return two columns--a latitude column and a longitude column--from a geography instead of returning the geography as a single column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer over gis.stackexchange.com. The answer was in response to a different kind of question, which might be part of why I had a hard time finding it at first.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32680/postgis-convert-geographypoint-4326-to-gps/32729#32729

The solution is to cast the geography to a geometry first:

`SELECT ST_X(geogcolumn::geometry), ST_Y(geogcolumn::geometry) FROM thetable;`